# Is it possible to remove viewscreen weather effects?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I'm playing No Man's Sky on PC (via Steam), and I've noticed that when I start my game on a hazardous planet, the "weather effects" on the viewscreen seem to persist even when I leave the planet. **Is there a way to disable the weather effects entirely?** I don't find it adds very much to the ambience on hazardous planets, beyond making it even more difficult to see than usual. (By weather effects I mean the "frost" that builds up on the edges of glacial planets, or the yellow toxic film that builds up on toxic planets. etc.)

As an example, I started today's session in a base that I have on a glacial moon. Afterwards I left and went to the anomaly to talk to Polo. As you can see from the screenshot below, the "frosting" on the edges of my viewscreen are still present even though I'm in the perfectly climate-controlled anomaly. :(

[image: Screenshot onboard the Anomaly]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not appear to be any in-built way to remove these effects, both from personal experience and further research. [I found another user asking about it on the Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/0/2254559285375182485/?l=german), but they were met with quite a bit of hostility.

If you're playing on PC, you have the option of using mods. As an example, I found [the *"No Weather Overlay"* mod at Nexus Mods](https://www.nexusmods.com/nomanssky/mods/1177/). The mod provides the following changes to the base game:

> This mod replaces the COLD, HOT, RADIATION and TOXIC screen effects intended to exaggerate the hazardous nature of worlds inundated with these traits with a TRANSPARENT texture to outright remove them without deleting files or reassociating MBINs.
>
> It does not remove the world effects associated with dust, fog or storms, which in my opinion is a bit more realistic. 
> Moving forward, I may remove these effects as well in a seperate version if there is enough desire but it will come with the caveate of file conflicts as I suspect many ENVIRONMENT mods alter these textures.
> **...**
> The following files get modified by these mods:
> TEXTURES/EFFECTS/FULLSCREEN/HAZARDS/COLD.dds
> TEXTURES/EFFECTS/FULLSCREEN/HAZARDS/HOT.dds
> TEXTURES/EFFECTS/FULLSCREEN/HAZARDS/RADIATION.dds
> TEXTURES/EFFECTS/FULLSCREEN/HAZARDS/TOXIC.dds>/p>
> Any other mods that modify the same files, will not be compatible.
> **[- Description of the *"No Weather Overlay"* mod at Nexus Mods](https://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/0/2254559285375182485/?l=german)**